# Removing unwanted variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hi I am trying to remove unwanted variables from my list.
This is my function:

```
(defun remove-vars (list)
  (loop for x in list do
         (print x))))
```

I want to pass in this `(get-vars '(A (NOT B) C))`
and print out

```
A
B
C
```

but instead I am printing out

```
A
(NOT B)
C
Nil
```

is there a way to remove the parenthesis and the not from the list? Any guidance would be appreciated if the list was bigger with a b c d i would like to remove all instances of not and parenthesis. I guess what pseudocode would be to loop through check if "( ) or not exist in x" then delete those from the list

Comment: parenthesis can't be removed. They are only an artifact of printing a list. If there is a list, Lisp needs parentheses around them. `NOT`, `A`, `B`, ... are not variables in a list, they are symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code loops through and prints each element of the list, unconditionally.

When you pass it `(A (NOT B) C)`, it is printing every element, one of which is the list `(NOT B)`, and the loop is printing that list. The parentheses are output by the printer to represent that the element being printed is a list.

You need some logic to check if each element is something you'd like to not print, like the symbol `NOT` or nil, and recurse down when you see a something you want to examine further, such as a list.

Comment: Quotes are not part of data structures. `'(a b c)` is not the list, `(a b c)`is the list. A quote is only used to prevent evaluation.

Comment: I understand that, I was typing it as I'd type it in a REPL, mostly out of habit. Thanks for the edit and comment. I also was thinking I should maybe make it clearer that the parentheses aren't part of the list, but being printed by the printer, so I'll just do that now.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is flatten the list and remove the NOT's like this:

```
(defun flatten (var-list)
  (cond ((null var-list) nil)
        ((atom var-list) (list var-list))
        (t (mapcan #'flatten var-list))))

(defun get-vars (var-list)
  (remove 'NOT (flatten var-list)))

(get-vars '(A (NOT B) C))
```

Hope it helps